# Get a set of strings using Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following naming pattern.

**YEAR-REG-TYPE-LANGUAGE-CAMP-NAME_EMAIL#**

How can I get all string after NAME using Excel formula? 

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `MID`, `FIND`, and `LEN` like so

```
=MID(A2, FIND("NAME", A2, 1)+4, LEN(A2))
```

Where your data is in cell `A2`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking it that you don't want to find the actual word 'Name' as it's the pattern you're after, so 'Name' will be an actual name and 'Email' will be an actual email address.

If you want to find `NAME_EMAIL#` then you need everything to the right of the 5th `-`.
This formula will return that:
`=MID($A$1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"-","|",5))+1,LEN($A$1))`

Returning just the email is easier as it has the only underscore in the string:
`=MID($A$1,FIND("_",$A$1)+1,LEN($A$1))`